# multi if statment in my expression with shorthand if statment in angular

Tags: angular

I have an expression that has three checks that need to be done.

so i was thinking of using it as follow:

```
{{payload.finance ==='value1' ? 'message 1'}}
```

but i need to do 3 checks so is there a way to do something like

```
{{payload.finance ==='value1' ? 'message 1' || payload.finance === 'value2' ? 'message 2' : 'message 2'}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be missing a colon in the first condition. Try the following

```html
{{  payload.finance === 'value1' ? 'message 1' : payload.finance === 'value2' ? 'message 2' : 'message 3'}}
```